# My SOLR Admin page is infected by a XMR.OMINE.ORG virus, I don't know how to fix it

Tags: solr, virus

Strange thing happening to me.
Every time I load my SOLR admin page, the developer console shows me that a XMR.OMINE.ORG virus is trying to inject a JS in the page.
That happens 1000 times and makes the page hang.

What is strange is that it happens ONLY when I access the SOLR admin page and not with any other page on the same web server or an internet page.

I tried everything...nothing works.

Here is the console log:

---

> A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, , is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See  for more details.
>
> VM41 v7.js:1 [Violation] 'setInterval' handler took 280ms
>
> VM1939 v7.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://xmr.omine.org:8181/' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

---

I tried:

- Running AVAST for MAC -> the web shield detects the virus but the scan doesn't and it doesn't remove it
- Malwarebytes for Mac -> nothing found or removed
- Running antivirus on web server => ongoing
- When I access it from another laptop => it works, no injection => **CORRECTION, same problem on other machines, seems server-related**

I'm lost, I can't run the SOLR admin and I have 504 errors on SOLR updates

Can you help me please?

Nico

Comment: If it works properly from a different computer - and there is no sign of the injected javascript when loading it on that computer - are you sure you don't have a browser extension installed that's hijacking the content? Try with a different browser (i.e. try Firefox instead of Chrome) on the same computer and see if that alters anything. Check if there's a proxy server defined locally that your browsers has been configured to use .. etc.

Comment: Hi MatsLindh, I tried on Chrome, Firefox and Safari => same issue everywhere.

Comment: I also checked the extensions, no trace of anything unusual

Comment: CORRECTION: I tested on other computers => ALL have the problem, so it's related to the server. As my SOLR runs in a docker, I will try installing another container and see if the problems persists. Only the SOLR pages are infected, not my web server and other applications that are served from the Synology, and not from the Docker container SOLR